# Tomcat Server gave the error 404-requested resource not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I use JDK7 and tomcat7,after compiling my servlet and copied the relevant files from my project directory to tomcat server directory.but when I want to run the servlet in my browser,I got the error 404-resource not available.

Comment: here is the log files details that i get

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Nov/2013:23:46:09 +0530] "GET /ch1/Serv1 HTTP/1.1" 404 969
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Nov/2013:23:48:26 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11444
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Nov/2013:23:50:02 +0530] "GET /ch1/Serv1 HTTP/1.1" 404 969
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Nov/2013:23:54:34 +0530] "GET /ch1/Serv1 HTTP/1.1" 404 969

yes i check the server by using "localhost:8080" i get the tomcat home page.

Comment: Servlet class:
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

 public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet
  {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse   response)throws IOException
         {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
  out.println("<html>" +
       "<body>" +
       "<h1 align=center> HF\'s Chapter1 Servlet</h1>"
       + "<br>" + today + "</body>" + "</html>");
  }
  }

Comment: and the web.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instances"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
   http://java.sun.com./xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4">
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet is fine. I tested it on my machine and it works.

The `web.xml` shouldn't contain `;` after the namespace declarations, but that may be the result of copy-pasting (the `http://` prefix isn't visible either in your answer).

Check the directory structure if it meets the requirements and restart Tomcat. I would recommend compiling the project to a war file instead of copy pasting several files from your project directory to Tomcat.

Comment: I checked my web.xml file and there is no ; in that. I want to know about the tomcat directory,that's why I did not use the war file in my project.